# 'no version information available' warning when starting pypy on centos6

Tags: centos, pypy

I've been struggling with this for a few hours and not sure how to get rid of it(or if it'll cause any problems for me) but I keep getting the following warnings when I start pypy on centos6:

```
[root@domU-123 bin]# ./pypy 
./pypy: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8: no version information available (required by ./pypy)
./pypy: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: no version information available (required by ./pypy)
Python 2.7.2 (0e28b379d8b3, Feb 09 2012, 19:41:03)
[PyPy 1.8.0 with GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``"Let's go." - "We can't" - "Why
not?" - "We're waiting for a Translation." - (despairingly) "Ah!"''
>>>>
```

Here's a copy of my install script(I install this on a fresh centos system):

```
#install pypy
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy-1.8-linux64.tar.bz2
tar xvf pypy*

yum -y install openssl098e
ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e /usr/lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8
ln -s /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
ln -s /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.4 /lib64/libbz2.so.1.0
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix it? Am I missing a package or does something need to be configured?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the version of libssl and libcrypto. Check this thread, it might give you ideas on where to look: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pypy/8565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the dreaded binary compatibility problem with linux

basically if you don’t have the same distro/version as the build server,
you can assume it may break due to distro policies wrt libs

for recent builds, its likely broken on anything that’s not similar
to whats on the build server (which runs a recent ubuntu)

(before it was a debian, but that broke openssl in strange ways on a regular basis)

since distros seem break general binary compatibility on regular basis,
this is not something that the pypy core team will spend more time on

external maintainers wanted